# Two functions not working together, but work by themselves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a Spotify script which puts the now playing song into a `<div>` from html, they work by themselves but when I put them both on the same page, only One of them show:

HTML:

```
<div id="rss"></div>
<div id="lukerss"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    var e = "LukeAssassin";
    window.lfmRecentTrack = function(t) {
        var n = (new Array).concat(t.recenttracks.track)[0];
        var album, spurl;
        if (n.album["#text"]) {
            album = " (from " + n.album["#text"] + ")";
        } else {
            album = "";
        }
        try {
            var spotify = new XMLHttpRequest();
            spotify.open("GET", "https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=" + encodeURIComponent(n.artist["#text"] + " - " + n.name), false);
            spotify.send();
            var spotresp = JSON.parse(spotify.responseText);
            if (spotresp["tracks"].length > 0) {
                //var urisplit = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"].split(":");
                //spurl = " https://open.spotify.com/" + urisplit[1] + "/" + urisplit[2];
                spurl = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"];
            } else {
                console.log("spotify: couldn't get url");
                spurl = "";
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("spotify: " + e.message);
            spurl = "";
        }
        var r2 = "" + n.name + " by " + n.artist["#text"];
        var element = document.getElementById("lukerss");
        element.innerHTML = r2;
    }
    var n = document.createElement("script");
    n.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    n.setAttribute("src", "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=" + e + "&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&limit=1&format=json&callback=window.lfmRecentTrack");
    document.body.appendChild(n)
})();
```

```
(function () {
    var e2 = "DeviousRunner";
    window.lfmRecentTrack = function(t2) {
        var n2 = (new Array).concat(t2.recenttracks.track)[0];
        var album, spurl;
        if (n2.album["#text"]) {
            album = " (from " + n2.album["#text"] + ")";
        } else {
            album = "";
        }
        try {
            var spotify = new XMLHttpRequest();
            spotify.open("GET", "https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=" + encodeURIComponent(n2.artist["#text"] + " - " + n2.name), false);
            spotify.send();
            var spotresp = JSON.parse(spotify.responseText);
            if (spotresp["tracks"].length > 0) {
                //var urisplit = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"].split(":");
                //spurl = " https://open.spotify.com/" + urisplit[1] + "/" + urisplit[2];
                spurl = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"];
            } else {
                console.log("spotify: couldn't get url");
                spurl = "";
            }
        } catch (e2) {
            console.log("spotify: " + e.message);
            spurl = "";
        }
        var r = "" + n2.name + " by " + n2.artist["#text"];
        var element = document.getElementById("rss");
        element.innerHTML = r;
    }
    var n2 = document.createElement("script");
    n2.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    n2.setAttribute("src", "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=" + e2 + "&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&limit=1&format=json&callback=window.lfmRecentTrack");
    document.body.appendChild(n2)
})();
```

CSS:

```
#rss {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#lukerss {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    color:red;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

The fiddle is also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GmT9K/2/) - it seems like the last one is the one that shows. If anyone has a solution, please feel free to share :)

Comment: Thanks for handing us that api key.

Comment: It's not mine, so its fine.

Comment: _"Thanks for handing us the key to your vault of gold"_ _"It's not my gold, so it's fine."_
I assume that application has an api key for a reason.

Comment: Are you here to help? or contradict me about an api key?

Comment: I think you will find `Cerbrus` meant you should *never* expose private API keys on Stack Overflow. If it is going to get misused in a hurry this is the right place :)

Comment: The point of what Cerbrus was saying is that API keys, whether they belong to you or someone else are private and should never be posted.  You can always just remove it or use a variable when posting a question on a site like SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use different names for `window.lfmRecentTrack` in the two functions.